# How to address multidimensional json array in Python

Tags: python, json, multidimensional-array

I have a following context received from a query in Python script (an example):

> {
>     "active": false,
>     "owner": "user1",
>     "content": [
>       {
>         "recordType": "test",
>         "record": [
>           {
>             "id": "1",
>             "date": "Nov 30, 2017 12:00:00 AM",
>             "link": "http://localhost",
>             "Size": 1234,
>           },
>           {
>             "id": "3",
>             "date": "Nov 21, 2017 06:00:00 AM",
>             "link": "http://localhost",
>             "Size": 3241,
>           }      ]
>       }
>     ]
>   }

making this to json array works without errors:

```
data = json.loads(*string_above*)
```

as a result this works ok:

```
print data["owner"]
```

> user1

also this is ok:

```
print data["content"]
```

> [
>       {
>         "recordType": "test",
>         "record": [
>           {
>             "id": "1",
>             "date": "Nov 30, 2017 12:00:00 AM",
>             "link": "http://localhost",
>             "Size": 1234,
>           },
>           {
>             "id": "3",
>             "date": "Nov 21, 2017 06:00:00 AM",
>             "link": "http://localhost",
>             "Size": 3241,
>           }      ]}

Now my problem is how can I make this a multidimensional array?

E.g. command

```
print data["content"]["record"]
```

gives an error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

what I was hoping to get is:

> {
>             "id": "1",
>             "date": "Nov 30, 2017 12:00:00 AM",
>             "link": "http://localhost",
>             "Size": 1234,
>           },
>           {
>             "id": "3",
>             "date": "Nov 21, 2017 06:00:00 AM",
>             "link": "http://localhost",
>             "Size": 3241,
>           }

Found many different comments on this kind of problem with Google but is there no a simple solution - what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer - `data["content"]` is a `list` with one element. You could use

```
print data["content"][0]["record"]
```

You could use online json fromatters (for example [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)) to explore your json data.

Comment: Thanks, this I can understand and agree with n8sty as well for being confused :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused. Let's fix that. The initial object you're returning is a `dict` not an array (`list` in Python speak).

```
d = { "active": False, "owner": "user1", "content": [ { "recordType": "test", "record": [ { ": id": "1", "date": "Nov 30, 2017 12:00:00 AM", "link": "http://localhost", "Size": 1234, }, { "id": "3", "date": "Nov 21, 2017 06:00:00 AM", "link": "http://localhost", "Size": 3241, } ] } ] }
isinstance(d, dict)
# True
```

The thing you grab from `d` is a `list`:

```
isinstance(data["content"], list)
# True
```

whose elements need to be referenced using `int`. So, to get the first element of `data['content']` which is a `dict`, you would do

```
c0 = data['content'][0]
isinstance(c0, dict)
# True
```